# ASP.NET 5 can't use Response

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpresponse, system.web

I'm trying to output information from my database to an Excel File using ASP.Net 5. In my controller I have two methods for this.

```
public void ExportData()
    {
        var data = new[]{
                           new{ Name="Ram", Email="ram@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" },
                           new{ Name="Shyam", Email="shyam@techbrij.com", Phone="159-222-1596" },
                           new{ Name="Mohan", Email="mohan@techbrij.com", Phone="456-222-4569" },
                           new{ Name="Sohan", Email="sohan@techbrij.com", Phone="789-456-3333" },
                           new{ Name="Karan", Email="karan@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-1234" },
                           new{ Name="Brij", Email="brij@techbrij.com", Phone="111-222-3333" }
                  };

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Contact.xls");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        WriteTsv(data, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Output);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }


public void WriteTsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, TextWriter output)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            output.Write(prop.DisplayName); // header
            output.Write("\t");
        }
        output.WriteLine();
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                output.Write(prop.Converter.ConvertToString(
                     prop.GetValue(item)));
                output.Write("\t");
            }
            output.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

I am forced to use **System.Web** because I have no idea how to export an excel file using ASP.Net 5, thus I'm currently using **dnx451**. I deleted **dnxcore50** from my project.json in order to use System.Web.

However when calling the top method, I get the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
```

The original example of this code used:

```
Response
```

Instead of:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
```

I cannot use just use **Response** because it uses Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpResponse instead of System.Web

Using System.Web.HttpResponse also doesn't work because it gives the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

This is my first web application and this problem has caused me to grind into a halt. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use System.Web. One of the goals of ASP.Net Core was to remove the dependency on System.Web. Since ASP.Net Core is does not depend on System.Web the HttpContext et al. won't be initialized and hence NRE. You can use `IHttpContextAccessor` to get HttpContext in ASP.Net Core and access the `Response` from there.

Comment: Thanks, I can use response now.

However the WriteTsv<T> method won't compile because its unsuported in ASP.Net Core.

Seems switching to ASP.Net 5 was a huge mistake.

Comment: Why won't it compile? Maybe you are missing some references?

Comment: This  example uses `System.ComponentModel` which is not fully compatible with DNX Core 5.0 thus my project won't compile.

I also can't find the equivalent of Response.Output using `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: I got it to work by deleting dnxcore50 from the Project.Json.

All I need to do now is call the 2nd method but I don't know the equivalent of `Response.Output` using  `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: I guess you use HttpResponse.Body - this will give you a stream and you can write to this stream using a StreamWriter?

Comment: Everything seems to work except the document shows up empty.

By the way thank you so much for the help. I used `TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body)` to create the method and called the second method using  `WriteTsv(data, tw)`

Comment: If you got that far it is probably something simple. Just in case turn on logging - maybe this is an exception and you get a blank page because of 500 (internal server error).